# Плавность анимации morphSVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Есть такая анимация, выполнена с помощью плагина TweenMax:

```js
//OVERLAY

var trigger = $('#trigger');
var close = $('#close');

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: false, yoyo: true, repeat:-1, delay: 0
});


TweenMax.set("path", {scale: 0, transformOrigin: "center center"});


tl.to("#start-4", 1, { 
    morphSVG: "#start-1", 
    scale: .25,
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    //fill: "#F40B37",    
  })
  .to("#start-4", 1, { 
    morphSVG: "#start-2", 
    scale: .5,
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    //fill: "#F40B37",    
  })
  .to("#start-4", 1, { 
    morphSVG: "#start-5", 
    scale: 1,
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    //fill: "#F40B37",    
  })
  .to("#start-4", 1, { 
    morphSVG: "#start-3", 
    scale: 2,
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    //fill: "#F40B37",    
  });



// tl.pause();

// trigger.on('click', openOverlay);
// close.on('click', closeOverlay);

function openOverlay(){
  tl.play();
}

function closeOverlay(){
  tl.reverse();
}
```

```css
/*Overlay styles*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#start-1, #start-2, #start-3, #start-5 {
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 1;
   display: none;
}

#trigger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #F40B37 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>




<!--Overlay-->

<button id="trigger">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>


<svg class="overlay" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="0 0 170 170">
  

 <path id="start-1" fill="#52AC62" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.923,51.201c2.988-0.742,3.99-2.748,5.161-5.603
  c1.058-2.579,3.033-5.813,3.236-7.994c0.485-5.217,0.043-15.378,5.651-17.536c3.636-1.399,8.47,2.513,11.415,3.577
  c4.348,1.57,7.71-6.052,10.883-8.832c2.37-2.077,6.069-2.588,8.079-5.083c2.222-2.759,5.738-3.773,8.563-5.655
  c2.862-1.904,3.764-0.895,7.431-1.048c3.817-0.16,5.944,1.501,9.435,2.263c3.331,0.726,6.87,0.041,10.285,0.324
  c3.674,0.305,7.466,1.455,10.497,3.309c6.218,3.803,11.5,3.126,18.586,3.799c7.848,0.746,10.848,5.583,12.917,12.693
  c1.952,6.705,1.176,12.804,8.411,16.318c3.15,1.53,6.96,2.085,9.706,4.186c2.812,2.151,3.569,5.483,4.758,8.552
  c2.267,5.848,2.577,12.279,4.029,18.358c1.651,6.919,2.311,11.566,0.907,18.744c-0.597,3.047-1.133,5.983-2.902,8.41
  c-2.004,2.748-4.295,4.57-5.743,7.73c-2.89,6.303-4.656,12.553-7.449,19.074c-2.499,5.831-5.782,11.307-9.462,16.425
  c-1.92,2.672-4.624,4.454-7.712,5.575c-2.077,0.752-4.152,0.817-6.066,2.237c-1.189,0.881-1.786,2.293-3,3.012
  c-2.518,1.491-5.943,0.834-8.732,1.197c-3.392,0.441-5.9-0.031-8.085,1.932c-2.416,2.172-4.453,2.495-7.109,4.438
  c-3.866,2.827-5.917,4.63-10.745,2.914c-3.865-1.372-7.096-2.374-11.311-0.89c-2.414,0.851-4.251,3.538-6.544,3.474
  c-2.505-0.07-10.564-3.784-13.33-5.252c-2.68-1.421-4.264-2.59-6.867-4.362c-5.623-3.828-7.386-5.923-13.896-7.194
  c-3.162-0.617-8.052-1.164-10.019-3.855c-2.463-3.369,0.53-8.03-2.651-10.27c-6.558-4.617-7.133-9.071-10.018-13.314
  c-1.467-2.157-4.117-5.113-4.774-7.433c-0.745-2.631,0.205-6.455,0.33-8.977c0.235-4.776-1.453-7.479-2.994-11.569
  c-1.364-3.617-1.889-8.868-0.971-12.933c1.148-5.081,3.57-10.717,2.498-15.826c-0.996-4.744-3.107-5.69-2.388-11.067
  c2.065-3.473,7.046-3.829,10.634-3.871"/>

 <path id="start-2" fill="#FFF343" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M7.512,76.449c0.45-8.144,2.827-15.645,9.393-21.093
  c4.418-3.667,9.011-4.73,12.891-9.345c2.628-3.125,5.293-6.05,7.524-9.502c2.064-3.194,2.932-7.135,4.896-10.395
  c2.824-4.688,5.656-4.741,10.691-5.114c4.353-0.323,6.286-0.83,10.144-2.784c4.665-2.362,7.547-3.434,12.651-3.435
  c3.428-0.001,7.384,0.579,10.761,0.008c5.142-0.87,9.252-3.657,14.909-3.118c5.167,0.494,10.335,3.579,14.39,6.834
  c3.588,2.882,5.82,6.917,10.083,9.075c3.989,2.019,8.757,3.976,13.017,5.58c3.082,1.159,7.814,2.686,10.029,5.276
  c4.707,5.504,2.894,14.024,6.661,19.874c3.791,5.89,8.426,11.497,6.477,18.978c-0.594,2.271-2.206,4.038-2.684,6.25
  c-0.367,1.699-0.11,3.725-0.356,5.443c-0.468,3.26-1.478,6.032-1.795,9.405c-0.373,3.964-1.176,7.843-1.66,11.746
  c-0.407,3.254,0.951,7.256,0.035,10.374c-1.183,4.028-6.489,5.559-9.891,7.102c-1.876,0.851-4.109,1.53-5.768,2.823
  c-1.651,1.289-2.545,3.228-4.295,4.239c-3.635,2.103-7.167,3.099-10.062,6.651c-2.658,3.266-2.216,7.714-3.767,11.322
  c-4.042,9.411-13.359,4.774-21.163,3.362c-7.329-1.325-15.369-0.612-22.757-0.271c-5.625,0.261-11.407-0.506-17.018-0.024
  c-3.014,0.258-3.961,1.082-6.17-0.754c-3.551-2.948-5.876-11.118-8.055-15.49c-3.782-7.592-8.147-14.085-15.367-18.701
  c-3.693-2.36-7.471-4.982-11.145-7.516c-3.349-2.311-7.848-4.413-9.604-8.224c-4.475-9.71,6.007-8.155,11.758-9.836
  c3.003-0.879,6.63-4.305,5.389-7.859c-1.065-3.052-7.149-2.712-9.951-3.11C12.244,83.446,10.273,82.548,7.512,76.449"/>

  
 <path id="start-3" fill="#D24A43" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17.874,124.296c-1.827-0.743-1.694-7.781-2.554-10.107
  c-1.585-4.293-4.309-7.507-6.37-11.245c-1.813-3.286-1.73-7.175-1.716-11.087c0.018-4.6-1.277-8.519-1.701-13.076
  c-0.421-4.531,2.179-7.621,3.712-11.601c1.911-4.964,3.651-10.337,6.522-14.831c3.387-5.298,9.049-3.746,14.086-7.576
  c3.569-2.714,5.293-6.121,6.746-10.193c1.558-4.366,1.909-8.951,6.034-11.648c4.203-2.748,9.052-0.949,13.641-1.952
  c5.958-1.302,8.593-5.828,13.522-7.787c4.862-1.93,10.139,1.256,15.021,0.375c4.643-0.838,7.103-4.105,12.292-3.364
  c4.623,0.661,11.456,5.96,16.098,6.842c9.034,1.717,16.13-3.378,22.981,5.107c2.99,3.702-0.266,6.834,3.83,10.214
  c4.036,3.329,10.583,7.672,13.62,12.13c5.561,8.157,9.893,13.69,10.853,23.195c0.36,3.57-3.967,10.129-4.682,13.617
  c-0.906,4.41-2.125,6.809-2.341,11.814c-0.183,4.209,0.212,8.357,0.425,12.446c0.3,5.747-2.751,7.936-3.852,13.194
  c-0.564,2.693,0.216,3.533-1.809,5.886c-1.535,1.784-4.121,1.88-5.507,3.998c-2.061,3.149-5.766,8.779-6.069,12.665
  c-0.495,6.318-0.735,9.27-7.022,12.342c-4.283,2.094-9.701,3.206-14.47,3.404c-5.207,0.217-5.39,0.947-10.427,1.276
  c-5.585,0.364-13.936,2.24-19.354,1.317c-10.016-1.705-19.096-3.062-29.589-3.02c-6.194,0.025-8.89-1.298-11.524-6.737
  c-2.417-4.993-6.288-8.909-9.109-13.673c-2.097-3.541-4.516-8.226-8.307-10.232c-3.529-1.869-10.427-0.852-13.832-1.694"/>

  
 <path id="start-4" fill="#6558A0" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M20.758,115.292c-1.193,0.02,0.61,0.135-0.58-0.132
  c-3.398-11.825-10.059-23.922-9-37.212c1.1-13.835,10.051-16.348,17.031-24.507c7.069-8.264,10.822-18.573,19.16-24.775
  c7.271-5.407,17.401-5.04,25.387-7.158c11.014-2.917,17.839-9.469,28.498-14.413c14.479-6.717,7.911,6.418,15.567,19.119
  c14.864,24.652,40.51,10.604,45.67,49.094c3.712,27.69-12.301,26.734-28.64,31.256c-17.959,4.97-30.88,13.657-42.44,32.525
  c-11.17,18.233-21.476,19.114-37.871,13.229C36.105,146.06,28.542,135.99,20.758,115.292"/>

  
 <path id="start-5" fill="#D7569C" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M16.563,122.124c0.376-1.767-4.278-8.624-3.268-11.312
  c-3.398-11.825,2.774-13.374,3.833-26.665c1.1-13.835-3.646-32.174,3.333-40.333c7.069-8.264,18.365-4.071,26.703-10.273
  c7.271-5.407,9.645-21.271,17.63-23.389c11.014-2.917,25.597,6.763,36.255,1.818c14.479-6.717,21.756,3.477,29.412,16.177
  c14.865,24.652,26.664,13.545,31.824,52.035c3.713,27.69-17.719,37.239-24.824,52.632c-10,21.667-18.439-1.535-30,17.333
  c-11.17,18.233-36.939,2.553-53.333-3.333c-17.435-6.258-37.659-2.354-37.567-25.002"/>

</svg>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/JMWEWe)

Не могу решить проблему плавности перехода от одной  фигуры к другой.

**Вопрос:** как для данной анимации можно решить проблему плавности? В идеале хотелось бы иметь вид растекающейся жидкости или хотя бы [плавность как тут](https://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/qLxAB?limit=all&page=2&q=morph), потому что сейчас каждый шаг сильно заметен,- при изменении состояния и увеличении размеров фигуры.

**P.S:** Эффект должен быть, как если бы эмалевую краску (вязкую жидкость) вылили на стол. В конце должен быть залит весь экран.

Comment: А формы обязательно в точности повторить твои на этапах трансформации? Или можно например так,- упала почти круглая капля, а потом плавно потекла, расползаясь во все стороны, как настоящая капля чернил на бумаге? Минимальный размер капли на первом этапе какой? И максимальный на финише? Короче какие габариты размазанная капля с потеками во все стороны должна занять?

Comment: Хотелось бы такие же формы и оставить, но как вариант можно и каплю, с 0 до заполнения всего экрана

Comment: я с твоей первой формы пойду start-1, а вот до какого размера увеличить надо? Похоже проблема не плавности, именно в не оптимальной форме прорисовки у тебя зарыта. Поэтому и спросил, до какого размера надо плавно увеличивать. Я вроде вспоминаю, что ты хотела модальное окно каплей заливать. Какой размер его будет?

Comment: это будет overlay модального, поэтому заливать весь экран

Comment: Как то не понятно что в этой анимации хотите изменить?

Comment: @StackOverflow, да вот и сама не знаю, что изменить чтобы достичь плавного растекания. То ли функция есть более подходящая `ease`, то ли добавить какие-нибудь промежуточные значения, которые позволят добиться эффекта. Эффект должен быть как если бы эмалевую краску (густую, вязкую жидкость) вылели на стол)

Comment: Хорошо так уже понятно, попробую что то изменить и дать ответ.

Comment: @HamSter Нашел ошибку. Разрыв контура был. Точек много, сразу и не заметишь. Одна на другой лежала, но не были связаны, поэтому и скачки были. Сейчас исправляю, уже плавно получается растекание, как заказывала - масляная краска по полу растекается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот две проблемы которые я увидел в вашей анимации.

**Первая:**

> Вы запускали один за другим несколько изменений фигуры (`анимации - tl.to`).И после каждой завершенной анимации у вас на мили секунды были паузы. Плавность пропала.

**Второе:**

> Что бы добиться эффекта оптикания надо что бы во время анимации фигура изменяла вид (`свои границы.`).

Ну и убрав лишние промежуточные анимции надо оставить только одну. И для того что бы менять границы надо сделать новую фигуру (`path`). И в методе анимации дать новые координаты нашего объекта. Это делаем вот так в методе.

```
tl.to("#start-4", 5, { 
      morphSVG: "#start-4",
      attr:{d: "Здесь уже новые координаты нашей фигуры, даем те координаты фигуры которую при завершении хотим получить."}
```

Ну и наша оптикаемая анимация уже готова.

```js
//OVERLAY

var trigger = $('#trigger');
var close = $('#close');

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: false, x:"+=20", yoyo: true, repeat:-1, delay: 0
});


TweenMax.set("path", {scale: 0, transformOrigin: "center center"});

tl.to("#start-4", 5, { 
  morphSVG: "#start-4",
  attr:{d: "M14.923,51.201c2.988-0.742,3.99-2.748,5.161-5.603 c1.058-2.579,3.033-5.813,3.236-7.994c0.485-5.217,0.043-15.378,5.651-17.536c3.636-1.399,8.47,2.513,11.415,3.577 c4.348,1.57,7.71-6.052,10.883-8.832c2.37-2.077,6.069-2.588,8.079-5.083c2.222-2.759,5.738-3.773,8.563-5.655 c2.862-1.904,3.764-0.895,7.431-1.048c3.817-0.16,5.944,1.501,9.435,2.263c3.331,0.726,6.87,0.041,10.285,0.324  c3.674,0.305,7.466,1.455,10.497,3.309c6.218,3.803,11.5,3.126,18.586,3.799c7.848,0.746,10.848,5.583,12.917,12.693  c1.952,6.705,1.176,12.804,8.411,16.318c3.15,1.53,6.96,2.085,9.706,4.186c2.812,2.151,3.569,5.483,4.758,8.552  c2.267,5.848,2.577,12.279,4.029,18.358c1.651,6.919,2.311,11.566,0.907,18.744c-0.597,3.047-1.133,5.983-2.902,8.41 c-2.004,2.748-4.295,4.57-5.743,7.73c-2.89,6.303-4.656,12.553-7.449,19.074c-2.499,5.831-5.782,11.307-9.462,16.425 c-1.92,2.672-4.624,4.454-7.712,5.575c-2.077,0.752-4.152,0.817-6.066,2.237c-1.189,0.881-1.786,2.293-3,3.012 c-2.518,1.491-5.943,0.834-8.732,1.197c-3.392,0.441-5.9-0.031-8.085,1.932c-2.416,2.172-4.453,2.495-7.109,4.438 c-3.866,2.827-5.917,4.63-10.745,2.914c-3.865-1.372-7.096-2.374-11.311-0.89c-2.414,0.851-4.251,3.538-6.544,3.474 c-2.505-0.07-10.564-3.784-13.33-5.252c-2.68-1.421-4.264-2.59-6.867-4.362c-5.623-3.828-7.386-5.923-13.896-7.194 c-3.162-0.617-8.052-1.164-10.019-3.855c-2.463-3.369,0.53-8.03-2.651-10.27c-6.558-4.617-7.133-9.071-10.018-13.314 c-1.467-2.157-4.117-5.113-4.774-7.433c-0.745-2.631,0.205-6.455,0.33-8.977c0.235-4.776-1.453-7.479-2.994-11.569 c-1.364-3.617-1.889-8.868-0.971-12.933c1.148-5.081,3.57-10.717,2.498-15.826c-0.996-4.744-3.107-5.69-2.388-11.067 c2.065-3.473,7.046-3.829,10.634-3.871"},
  scale: 1,
  ease: { ease: Sine.easeIn, x: "100%" }
});

//tl.pause();

//trigger.on('click', openOverlay);
//close.on('click', closeOverlay);

function openOverlay(){
  tl.play();
}
function closeOverlay(){
  tl.reverse();
}
```

```css
/*Overlay styles*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#start-1, #start-2, #start-3, #start-5 {
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 1;
   display: none;
}

#trigger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #F40B37 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomEase.min.js"></script>




<!--Overlay-->

<button id="trigger">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>


<svg class="overlay" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="0 0 170 170">
  

 <path id="start-1" fill="#52AC62" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.923,51.201c2.988-0.742,3.99-2.748,5.161-5.603
  c1.058-2.579,3.033-5.813,3.236-7.994c0.485-5.217,0.043-15.378,5.651-17.536c3.636-1.399,8.47,2.513,11.415,3.577
  c4.348,1.57,7.71-6.052,10.883-8.832c2.37-2.077,6.069-2.588,8.079-5.083c2.222-2.759,5.738-3.773,8.563-5.655
  c2.862-1.904,3.764-0.895,7.431-1.048c3.817-0.16,5.944,1.501,9.435,2.263c3.331,0.726,6.87,0.041,10.285,0.324
  c3.674,0.305,7.466,1.455,10.497,3.309c6.218,3.803,11.5,3.126,18.586,3.799c7.848,0.746,10.848,5.583,12.917,12.693
  c1.952,6.705,1.176,12.804,8.411,16.318c3.15,1.53,6.96,2.085,9.706,4.186c2.812,2.151,3.569,5.483,4.758,8.552
  c2.267,5.848,2.577,12.279,4.029,18.358c1.651,6.919,2.311,11.566,0.907,18.744c-0.597,3.047-1.133,5.983-2.902,8.41
  c-2.004,2.748-4.295,4.57-5.743,7.73c-2.89,6.303-4.656,12.553-7.449,19.074c-2.499,5.831-5.782,11.307-9.462,16.425
  c-1.92,2.672-4.624,4.454-7.712,5.575c-2.077,0.752-4.152,0.817-6.066,2.237c-1.189,0.881-1.786,2.293-3,3.012
  c-2.518,1.491-5.943,0.834-8.732,1.197c-3.392,0.441-5.9-0.031-8.085,1.932c-2.416,2.172-4.453,2.495-7.109,4.438
  c-3.866,2.827-5.917,4.63-10.745,2.914c-3.865-1.372-7.096-2.374-11.311-0.89c-2.414,0.851-4.251,3.538-6.544,3.474
  c-2.505-0.07-10.564-3.784-13.33-5.252c-2.68-1.421-4.264-2.59-6.867-4.362c-5.623-3.828-7.386-5.923-13.896-7.194
  c-3.162-0.617-8.052-1.164-10.019-3.855c-2.463-3.369,0.53-8.03-2.651-10.27c-6.558-4.617-7.133-9.071-10.018-13.314
  c-1.467-2.157-4.117-5.113-4.774-7.433c-0.745-2.631,0.205-6.455,0.33-8.977c0.235-4.776-1.453-7.479-2.994-11.569
  c-1.364-3.617-1.889-8.868-0.971-12.933c1.148-5.081,3.57-10.717,2.498-15.826c-0.996-4.744-3.107-5.69-2.388-11.067
  c2.065-3.473,7.046-3.829,10.634-3.871"/>

 <path id="start-2" fill="#FFF343" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M7.512,76.449c0.45-8.144,2.827-15.645,9.393-21.093
  c4.418-3.667,9.011-4.73,12.891-9.345c2.628-3.125,5.293-6.05,7.524-9.502c2.064-3.194,2.932-7.135,4.896-10.395
  c2.824-4.688,5.656-4.741,10.691-5.114c4.353-0.323,6.286-0.83,10.144-2.784c4.665-2.362,7.547-3.434,12.651-3.435
  c3.428-0.001,7.384,0.579,10.761,0.008c5.142-0.87,9.252-3.657,14.909-3.118c5.167,0.494,10.335,3.579,14.39,6.834
  c3.588,2.882,5.82,6.917,10.083,9.075c3.989,2.019,8.757,3.976,13.017,5.58c3.082,1.159,7.814,2.686,10.029,5.276
  c4.707,5.504,2.894,14.024,6.661,19.874c3.791,5.89,8.426,11.497,6.477,18.978c-0.594,2.271-2.206,4.038-2.684,6.25
  c-0.367,1.699-0.11,3.725-0.356,5.443c-0.468,3.26-1.478,6.032-1.795,9.405c-0.373,3.964-1.176,7.843-1.66,11.746
  c-0.407,3.254,0.951,7.256,0.035,10.374c-1.183,4.028-6.489,5.559-9.891,7.102c-1.876,0.851-4.109,1.53-5.768,2.823
  c-1.651,1.289-2.545,3.228-4.295,4.239c-3.635,2.103-7.167,3.099-10.062,6.651c-2.658,3.266-2.216,7.714-3.767,11.322
  c-4.042,9.411-13.359,4.774-21.163,3.362c-7.329-1.325-15.369-0.612-22.757-0.271c-5.625,0.261-11.407-0.506-17.018-0.024
  c-3.014,0.258-3.961,1.082-6.17-0.754c-3.551-2.948-5.876-11.118-8.055-15.49c-3.782-7.592-8.147-14.085-15.367-18.701
  c-3.693-2.36-7.471-4.982-11.145-7.516c-3.349-2.311-7.848-4.413-9.604-8.224c-4.475-9.71,6.007-8.155,11.758-9.836
  c3.003-0.879,6.63-4.305,5.389-7.859c-1.065-3.052-7.149-2.712-9.951-3.11C12.244,83.446,10.273,82.548,7.512,76.449"/>

  
 <path id="start-3" fill="#D24A43" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17.874,124.296c-1.827-0.743-1.694-7.781-2.554-10.107
  c-1.585-4.293-4.309-7.507-6.37-11.245c-1.813-3.286-1.73-7.175-1.716-11.087c0.018-4.6-1.277-8.519-1.701-13.076
  c-0.421-4.531,2.179-7.621,3.712-11.601c1.911-4.964,3.651-10.337,6.522-14.831c3.387-5.298,9.049-3.746,14.086-7.576
  c3.569-2.714,5.293-6.121,6.746-10.193c1.558-4.366,1.909-8.951,6.034-11.648c4.203-2.748,9.052-0.949,13.641-1.952
  c5.958-1.302,8.593-5.828,13.522-7.787c4.862-1.93,10.139,1.256,15.021,0.375c4.643-0.838,7.103-4.105,12.292-3.364
  c4.623,0.661,11.456,5.96,16.098,6.842c9.034,1.717,16.13-3.378,22.981,5.107c2.99,3.702-0.266,6.834,3.83,10.214
  c4.036,3.329,10.583,7.672,13.62,12.13c5.561,8.157,9.893,13.69,10.853,23.195c0.36,3.57-3.967,10.129-4.682,13.617
  c-0.906,4.41-2.125,6.809-2.341,11.814c-0.183,4.209,0.212,8.357,0.425,12.446c0.3,5.747-2.751,7.936-3.852,13.194
  c-0.564,2.693,0.216,3.533-1.809,5.886c-1.535,1.784-4.121,1.88-5.507,3.998c-2.061,3.149-5.766,8.779-6.069,12.665
  c-0.495,6.318-0.735,9.27-7.022,12.342c-4.283,2.094-9.701,3.206-14.47,3.404c-5.207,0.217-5.39,0.947-10.427,1.276
  c-5.585,0.364-13.936,2.24-19.354,1.317c-10.016-1.705-19.096-3.062-29.589-3.02c-6.194,0.025-8.89-1.298-11.524-6.737
  c-2.417-4.993-6.288-8.909-9.109-13.673c-2.097-3.541-4.516-8.226-8.307-10.232c-3.529-1.869-10.427-0.852-13.832-1.694"/>

  
 <path id="start-4" fill="#6558A0" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M20.758,115.292c-1.193,0.02,0.61,0.135-0.58-0.132
  c-3.398-11.825-10.059-23.922-9-37.212c1.1-13.835,10.051-16.348,17.031-24.507c7.069-8.264,10.822-18.573,19.16-24.775
  c7.271-5.407,17.401-5.04,25.387-7.158c11.014-2.917,17.839-9.469,28.498-14.413c14.479-6.717,7.911,6.418,15.567,19.119
  c14.864,24.652,40.51,10.604,45.67,49.094c3.712,27.69-12.301,26.734-28.64,31.256c-17.959,4.97-30.88,13.657-42.44,32.525
  c-11.17,18.233-21.476,19.114-37.871,13.229C36.105,146.06,28.542,135.99,20.758,115.292"/>

  
 <path id="start-5" fill="#D7569C" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M16.563,122.124c0.376-1.767-4.278-8.624-3.268-11.312
  c-3.398-11.825,2.774-13.374,3.833-26.665c1.1-13.835-3.646-32.174,3.333-40.333c7.069-8.264,18.365-4.071,26.703-10.273
  c7.271-5.407,9.645-21.271,17.63-23.389c11.014-2.917,25.597,6.763,36.255,1.818c14.479-6.717,21.756,3.477,29.412,16.177
  c14.865,24.652,26.664,13.545,31.824,52.035c3.713,27.69-17.719,37.239-24.824,52.632c-10,21.667-18.439-1.535-30,17.333
  c-11.17,18.233-36.939,2.553-53.333-3.333c-17.435-6.258-37.659-2.354-37.567-25.002"/>

</svg>
```

Вот второй вариант анимации с вашим плагином `TweenMax`.

Фигуры взял из другого ответа `Alexandr_T`.

Ну и что бы залить в конце весь экран надо и размеры дать побольше в анимации и в начале и в конце, это свойство `scale:`

```js
//OVERLAY

var trigger = $('#trigger');
var close = $('#close');

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: false, x:"+=10", yoyo: true, repeat:-1, delay: 0
});


TweenMax.set("path", {scale: 8, transformOrigin: "center center"});

tl.to("#start-4", 5, { 
  morphSVG: "#start-4",
  attr:{d: "m88.7 71.8c0 1.6-0.5 3.6 0.8 4.3 8 4.8 17.6-21.8 26.6-8.5 7.7 11.3-21.9 7.2-18.6 14.2 4.3 8.9 25.4-16.4 28.7-7.1 3.4 9.6-21.9 12.1-27.8 13-5.3 0.8 7.7 11.9 3.5 14.7-5.1 3.4-9.6-13.8-14.8-10.7-1.8 1.1 1.9 4.3 0.9 6.1-1.7 3.2-6.7 6.5-9.9 4.8-2.5-1.4 0.9-6.4-1-8.5-2.3-2.7-9.7 0.9-10.2-2.6-0.6-4.2 10.6-2.4 10.8-6.6 0.3-5.4-14.7-4.7-12.9-9.8 1.6-4.3 9.8 3 13.7 0.6 5.4-3.3 1.9-22 7.9-17.4 3.7 2.8 2.3 8 2.3 13.4z;M104.6 4.1C121.3 8.1 85.5 46 99.9 55.2 126.4 72.2 155.2-8.8 181.7 8.2c13.1 8.4 6.2 35-4.2 46.6-6 6.7-19.8-0.6-26.6 5.3-9.5 8.4-14.5 23.7-12.1 36.2 4.6 24.4 57.7 34.1 48 56.9-8.4 19.7-44 11.4-64.1 3.9-14.2-5.3-21.1-21.6-32.4-31.7-3.9-3.5-7-9.9-12.2-9.9C53.3 115.8 40.2 179.6 21.3 163.6 2.3 147.4 75.5 105 59.8 99.4 54.6 97.5-9.7 139.4-17.7 114.3-27.2 84.9 94.7 94.7 66.5 75.6 43.9 60.2-16.6 90.3-14.4 63.1-11.9 31.4 54.7 81.5 81.1 63.7 98.8 51.7 83.9-0.9 104.6 4.1Z;m102.7-2.3c9.2-0.9 19.5-1.2 29.1 0.2 22.9 3.4 64.6-8.7 63.9 5.8-1.5 31.2-4.3 42.5-2.6 63.7 0.3 4 2.1 7.7 2.5 11.7 0.7 7.8-0.6 15.6-0.6 23.4-0.1 21.8 7.3 44.1 1 65.3-4.3 14.4-50.8 5.9-76.4 6.7-9.6 0.3-19.2-0.7-28.8-0.6-8.2 0.1-16.3 0.9-24.5 0.8-14.4-0.1-28.8-1.9-43.2-2.1-9.7-0.1-9.7-2.2-29.1 0.7-61 9-23.2-51.1-23.9-63-0.9-15.8 7.4 0.2 8.3-30 0.8-27.3-5.8-45.9-1-78.5 1.5-10 41.9-3.1 62.8-3.8 20.8-0.7 42.9 1.7 62.6-0.3z"},
  scale: 35,
  ease: Power0.easeNone
});

//tl.pause();

//trigger.on('click', openOverlay);
//close.on('click', closeOverlay);

function openOverlay(){
  tl.play();
}
function closeOverlay(){
  tl.reverse();
}
```

```css
/*Overlay styles*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#start-1, #start-2, #start-3, #start-5 {
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 1;
   display: none;
}

#trigger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #F40B37 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomEase.min.js"></script>




<!--Overlay-->

<button id="trigger">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>


<svg class="overlay" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 170 170">
  
 <path id="start-4" scale="1"  stroke-miterlimit="10" d="m85 78.2c0.9 0 1.8 0.3 2.7 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.6 0.9 2.2 1.6 0.6 0.7 1.1 1.5 1.4 2.3 0.3 0.9 0.5 1.8 0.4 2.7 0 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.6 2.7-0.4 0.8-0.9 1.6-1.6 2.2-0.7 0.6-1.5 1.1-2.3 1.4-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.5-2.7 0.4-0.9 0-1.8-0.3-2.7-0.6-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.9-2.2-1.6-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.5-1.4-2.3-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.8-0.4-2.7 0-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.6-2.7 0.4-0.8 0.9-1.6 1.6-2.2 0.7-0.6 1.5-1.1 2.3-1.4 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.5 2.7-0.4z"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70929/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-overflow---morphsvg).

Answer (score 2):

Начало анимации заполнения - клик по любой точке холста SVG.

```html
<svg id="paint" class="overlay" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="100%" height="100%"  viewBox="0 0 170 170" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  

 <path id="start-1" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="m85 78.2c0.9 0 1.8 0.3 2.7 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.6 0.9 2.2 1.6 0.6 0.7 1.1 1.5 1.4 2.3 0.3 0.9 0.5 1.8 0.4 2.7 0 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.6 2.7-0.4 0.8-0.9 1.6-1.6 2.2-0.7 0.6-1.5 1.1-2.3 1.4-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.5-2.7 0.4-0.9 0-1.8-0.3-2.7-0.6-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.9-2.2-1.6-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.5-1.4-2.3-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.8-0.4-2.7 0-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.6-2.7 0.4-0.8 0.9-1.6 1.6-2.2 0.7-0.6 1.5-1.1 2.3-1.4 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.5 2.7-0.4z" style="fill:teal;stroke-width:0.3;stroke:none">
 <animate attributeName="d" dur="5s" values="m85 78.2c0.9 0 1.8 0.3 2.7 0.6 0.8 0.4 1.6 0.9 2.2 1.6 0.6 0.7 1.1 1.5 1.4 2.3 0.3 0.9 0.5 1.8 0.4 2.7 0 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.6 2.7-0.4 0.8-0.9 1.6-1.6 2.2-0.7 0.6-1.5 1.1-2.3 1.4-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.5-2.7 0.4-0.9 0-1.8-0.3-2.7-0.6-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.9-2.2-1.6-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.5-1.4-2.3-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.8-0.4-2.7 0-0.9 0.3-1.8 0.6-2.7 0.4-0.8 0.9-1.6 1.6-2.2 0.7-0.6 1.5-1.1 2.3-1.4 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.5 2.7-0.4z;m88.7 71.8c0 1.6-0.5 3.6 0.8 4.3 8 4.8 17.6-21.8 26.6-8.5 7.7 11.3-21.9 7.2-18.6 14.2 4.3 8.9 25.4-16.4 28.7-7.1 3.4 9.6-21.9 12.1-27.8 13-5.3 0.8 7.7 11.9 3.5 14.7-5.1 3.4-9.6-13.8-14.8-10.7-1.8 1.1 1.9 4.3 0.9 6.1-1.7 3.2-6.7 6.5-9.9 4.8-2.5-1.4 0.9-6.4-1-8.5-2.3-2.7-9.7 0.9-10.2-2.6-0.6-4.2 10.6-2.4 10.8-6.6 0.3-5.4-14.7-4.7-12.9-9.8 1.6-4.3 9.8 3 13.7 0.6 5.4-3.3 1.9-22 7.9-17.4 3.7 2.8 2.3 8 2.3 13.4z;M104.6 4.1C121.3 8.1 85.5 46 99.9 55.2 126.4 72.2 155.2-8.8 181.7 8.2c13.1 8.4 6.2 35-4.2 46.6-6 6.7-19.8-0.6-26.6 5.3-9.5 8.4-14.5 23.7-12.1 36.2 4.6 24.4 57.7 34.1 48 56.9-8.4 19.7-44 11.4-64.1 3.9-14.2-5.3-21.1-21.6-32.4-31.7-3.9-3.5-7-9.9-12.2-9.9C53.3 115.8 40.2 179.6 21.3 163.6 2.3 147.4 75.5 105 59.8 99.4 54.6 97.5-9.7 139.4-17.7 114.3-27.2 84.9 94.7 94.7 66.5 75.6 43.9 60.2-16.6 90.3-14.4 63.1-11.9 31.4 54.7 81.5 81.1 63.7 98.8 51.7 83.9-0.9 104.6 4.1Z;m102.7-2.3c9.2-0.9 19.5-1.2 29.1 0.2 22.9 3.4 64.6-8.7 63.9 5.8-1.5 31.2-4.3 42.5-2.6 63.7 0.3 4 2.1 7.7 2.5 11.7 0.7 7.8-0.6 15.6-0.6 23.4-0.1 21.8 7.3 44.1 1 65.3-4.3 14.4-50.8 5.9-76.4 6.7-9.6 0.3-19.2-0.7-28.8-0.6-8.2 0.1-16.3 0.9-24.5 0.8-14.4-0.1-28.8-1.9-43.2-2.1-9.7-0.1-9.7-2.2-29.1 0.7-61 9-23.2-51.1-23.9-63-0.9-15.8 7.4 0.2 8.3-30 0.8-27.3-5.8-45.9-1-78.5 1.5-10 41.9-3.1 62.8-3.8 20.8-0.7 42.9 1.7 62.6-0.3z" fill="freeze" begin="paint.click" restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path>
  

</svg>
```

Comment: Эффект хороший, но не с плагином `TweenMax` как сказал автор.

Comment: Поддерживаю, хороший эффект, но не TweenMax

Comment: @HamSter Тогда в вопросе не надо точно задавать чем надо сделать анимацию, а просто предпочтения какие то давать.

Comment: @StackOverflow, вроде, в вопросе точно определено с помощью чего хотелось бы реализовать, это twenmax, но если есть более интересные решения, то почему нет? Не мне, так кому-нибудь другому поможет. А о предпочтениях, если вы о минусе к вашему ответу, то это не я, мне все ответы нравятся)

Comment: @HamSter Нет я не об этом, это мне не волнует, просто предпочтения и строго то что вы хотите это другое. Можете дать мне начальную фигуру и конечную ? `path`? что бы дал такую анимацию с `tweenmax` которую вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Перерисовала немножко svg, получилось немного лучше (хотя и всеравно не намного лучше):

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/WdpBvP)

```js
//OVERLAY

var trigger = $('#trigger'),
    close = $('#close');

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: false, delay: 0, yoyo: true, repeat: 0
});


TweenMax.set("path", {scale: 0, transformOrigin: "center center"});


tl.to("#start-5", 1, { 
      morphSVG: "#start-4", 
      scale: .5,
      ease: Power0.easeNone,
    })
    .to("#start-5", 1, { 
      morphSVG: "#start-3", 
      scale: 1,
      ease: Power0.easeNone,    
    })
    .to("#start-5", 1, { 
      morphSVG: "#start-2", 
      scale: 1.5,
      ease: Power0.easeNone,  
    })
    .to("#start-5", 1, { 
      morphSVG: "#start-1", 
      scale: 2,
      ease: Power0.easeNone,   
    });


tl.pause();

trigger.on('click', openOverlay);
close.on('click', closeOverlay);

function openOverlay(){
  tl.play();
}

function closeOverlay(){
  tl.reverse();
}
```

```css
/*Overlay styles*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#start-1, #start-2, #start-3, #start-4 {
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 1;
   display: none;
}

#trigger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #F40B37 !important;
  stroke: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>




<!--Overlay-->

<button id="trigger">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>



<svg class="overlay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="700px" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 700 700">

  <path id="start-1" fill="#4D59A1" stroke="#0D0F0F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M275,683.665c-62-11.333-203.883-18.942-167.333-86.666
   c22.667-42-26.812-34.781-27.333-52c-0.667-22-37.333-16.664-43.446-57.932c-7.45-50.294-31.397-53.399-15.556-94.962
   C37,350.998,12.835,342.9,19.464,329.613c32.203-63.945-4.516-38.737-4.086-99.943c0.222-31.633,40.289-64,82.956-154.667
   c10.554-22.427,60.135,24.724,91.353,12.465c26.647-10.464,38.647-57.132,97.95-77.237C313.44,1.483,357,27.67,427.382,29.512
   C463.748,30.463,467.366,51.537,537,62.336c56.6,8.778,28,71.999,128.092,167.747c64.589,61.786,6.575,258.249-32.125,251.634
   C525,510.332,696.085,642.713,491.548,642.479C363.667,642.332,367.756,700.62,275,683.665z"/>

  <path id="start-2" fill="#D5584D" stroke="#0D0F0F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M235.818,602.115c4.778-49.535-35.227,15.245-47.152-60.782
   c-2.667-17-20.811-2.114-21.333-19.333c-0.667-22-6.866-25.307-13.667-30c-3.558-2.455-86.581-41.524-77.052-84.971
   c9.597-43.76,60.095-26.125,66.724-39.412c5.371-57.379-73.69,3.383-73.261-57.823c0.222-31.633,43.59-91.46,89.005-110.522
   c22.855-9.593,13.917-44.937,46.359-73.707c15.452-13.703,70.553-15.392,91.66-27.472c23.648-13.535,44.504-2.854,105.232-13.653
   c35.816-6.369,27.333,47.229,96.967,58.028c56.6,8.778,111.912,27.982,120.37,130.786C627,362.335,617.504,500.3,604,481.5
   c-70.5-25.75-67.652,160.665-161.666,128.42C396.234,594.108,233.084,630.457,235.818,602.115z"/>

  <path id="start-3" fill="#52AC62" stroke="#0D0F0F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M268.16,536.002c-0.788-1.075-14.488-24.159-16.41-25.752
   c-13.924-11.542-12.656-25.88-29.634-28.803c-8.042-1.385-12.065-13.004-18.866-17.697c-3.558-2.455-32.507-5.973-35-9.5
   c-2.625-3.716,3.5-25.75-3.58-35.297C142.723,405,150.5,368,140,332.5c-8.972-30.335,37-49.5,48.7-79.458
   c9.017-23.088,37.8-30.042,49.606-63.638c6.847-19.484,54.48,4.245,58.246-14.206C302,148.5,333,178.5,379.5,154.456
   c32.313-16.709,24.279,20.219,89.725,19.859C526.5,174,504.5,226,559.57,305.452c36.273,52.334-32.57,57.048-40.683,154.839
   C514,579,410,519,374.027,547.157C335.65,577.196,268.64,536.656,268.16,536.002z"/>

  <path id="start-4" fill="#FFF343" stroke="#0D0F0F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M305.028,464.799c-0.48-0.172-1.314-1.993-1.65-2.452
   c-0.553-0.754-1.134-1.487-1.745-2.193c-1.146-1.325-2.398-2.559-3.746-3.676c-9.765-8.095-22.705-8.306-34.611-10.355
   c-5.64-0.971-11.335-2.458-16.104-5.75c-2.495-1.722-4.649-3.889-6.397-6.362c-1.841-2.605-4.279-6.302-4.262-9.496
   c0.005-1.081-0.338-1.672-0.543-2.67c-0.22-1.074-0.08-2.709-0.825-3.599c-0.626-0.747-1.478-0.736-2.113-1.567
   c-1.045-1.364-1.57-3.413-2.124-5.012c-1.357-3.923-2.526-7.981-3.319-12.06c-5.431-18.903,5.462-32.966,7.155-54.209
   c1.758-22.115-6.057-46.413,5.1-59.454c11.299-13.209,36.369-14.714,49.697-24.628c11.622-8.643,13.174-26.578,25.939-29.963
   c17.606-4.662,48.781,9.226,65.817,1.323c23.143-10.736,21.187,6.369,33.422,26.669c23.759,39.404,56.214,20.84,64.462,82.363
   c5.932,44.26-29.943,43.123-36.146,63.393c-32.692,74.569-44.459,18.041-62.933,48.202
   C362.243,482.445,331.234,474.205,305.028,464.799z"/>


  <path id="start-5" fill="#635899" stroke="#0D0F0F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M286,382.333c-1.193,0.021,0.61,0.135-0.58-0.132
   c-3.398-11.825-10.059-23.922-9-37.212c1.1-13.835,10.051-16.348,17.031-24.507c7.069-8.264,10.822-18.573,19.16-24.775
   c7.271-5.407,17.401-5.04,25.387-7.158c11.014-2.917,17.84-9.469,28.498-14.413c14.479-6.717,7.912,6.418,15.566,19.119
   c14.864,24.652,40.512,10.604,45.672,49.094c3.711,27.69-12.303,26.734-28.642,31.256c-17.959,4.97-30.881,13.655-42.438,32.523
   c-11.171,18.232-21.477,19.114-37.872,13.229C301.347,413.102,293.784,403.031,286,382.333"/>
 </svg>
```